# How Add CSV Email Data to Database Table VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to upload an Email csv file to my application and parse into my database. Basically what I need is for the first column in the database to auto assign an ID and increment by 1 each time an entry is added. Then I need the code to read the first 3 columns of my CSV file and then change to the next line. Please see my VB code, database structure and CSV example also

```
Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'Upload and save the file
    Dim csvPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath)

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(3) {New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("Subject", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("Body", GetType(String)), New DataColumn("From", GetType(String))})

    Dim csvData As String = File.ReadAllText(csvPath)
    For Each row As String In csvData.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row) Then
            dt.Rows.Add()
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each cell As String In row.Split(","c)
                dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = cell
                i += 1
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Dim consString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(consString)
        Using sqlBulkCopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
            'Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Emails"
            con.Open()
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1IZN.png)

[CSV Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkbuN.png)

The error message I am getting is:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <"Subject"> in ID Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Answer (score 0):

From your table `ID` is utilising the `Identity` so you don't need to add `ID` to `dt.Columns.AddRange` Because it'll try inserting into ID column when it shouldn't.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I remove the ID from the dt.Columns.AddRange when I debug now I'm getting the following error: [Image of error](http://i328.photobucket.com/albums/l354/Diarmuid_Bogner/error_new_zps0ngmqf7a.png)

Comment: Did you change the array size to 2 like New DataColumn(2)

Comment: Yes I changed it to  `dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(2)`.

Comment: The problem is with the header text for column 3 on your CSV file, it's not Name as in your code it has some extra text appended to it

Comment: Make sure the column names on your CSV  matches as in your code

Comment: Okay if I change the column 3 to From should this resolve?

Comment: @DiarmuidBogner Yes it should

Comment: Okay I have edited the csv file removed the header completely and the other unneeded columns but I am getting the following error now.

Comment: Change the `body` field to allow nulls in your _Table Structure_ if that is how you intended otherwise make sure there is a value being inserted in that field on your table. Because it seems it is passing a `NULL` value somewhere

Comment: I changed all to allow nulls and it accepted the csv file however its parsed it in all over the place. Please see the image at http://s328.photobucket.com/user/Diarmuid_Bogner/media/database_data_zpsmqwrqvpf.png.html

Comment: @DiarmuidBogner you have not marked my answer as answering your first problem

Comment: thank you so much thus far I really appreciate it. Please see the image of the new csv at the following link http://i328.photobucket.com/albums/l354/Diarmuid_Bogner/new_csv_zpsd6jcx9wq.png